# Microsoft Service Fabric Cluster certificate creation and configuration

Tags: azure-service-fabric

After a couple of days of reading copius amounts of documentation without any success I thought I would ask the question here for some guidance.  I am trying to setup an Azure Service Fabric Cluster and get access to it via Powershell to allow me to manage the applications remotely and there seems to be a massive hole in the documentation, maybe for complete newbies like myself!

I have a Web API that needs to be accessed via Angular SPA running on mobile devices so I assume the end points need to be public and accessible without and form of challenge as the security is managed via JWT tokens.

As I see it the deployment of production environment should involve a few stages:-

1. Primary/Server certificate creation
2. Admin client certificate creation
3. Azure portal deployment
4. Development machine configuration to allow access to cluster via Powershell

Now I may have misunderstood the documentation so please feel free to correct me.

What have I done so far: -

1. I have created my cluster using the Microsoft self signed
   certificate facility as my Primary/Server certificate.
2. I have a wildcard certificate issued by a CA that I have installed
   as an Admin certificate on the server.
3. I have configured a CNAME entry that maps my *.cloudapp.azure.com
   onto a sub domain.

I can't connect to my cluster in anyway shape or form, I can't connect via Powershell using the Connect-ServiceFabricCluster and I can't browse to the Service Fabric Explorer it states access was denied :/

Can anybody provide me with some guidance on the process I need to follow to enable the connection or provide a link to some more verbose documentation that actually provides meaningful instruction on the process.

Answer (score 0):

This has been driving me nuts over the last few days so I have posted this step by step guide to help anybody whom is suffering the same misery.

PLEASE NOTE: These instructions use the built in Microsoft self signed certificate that the portal creates for you, production systems should have a valid CA issued certificate and I haven't tried this as yet!

## Create new Service Fabric Cluster via Portal

### Create a new Resource Group

1. Click on Resource Groups from left hand menu and click 'Add' button
2. Select subscription
3. Input Resource Group name
4. Select region "Northern Europe"
5. Click "Review + Create" and then click "Create"

### Create a new Service Fabric Cluster

1. Go to your new Resource Group
2. Click the "Add" button
3. Type "Service Fabric" into the search and select "Service Fabric Cluster"
4. Click the "Create" button at the foot of the page

### Configuring the Service Fabric Cluster

**Basics**

1. Input the name of your new cluster
2. Select required O/Select
3. Input your username and password (Ensure Google drive document is updated with details)
4. Select relevant subscription
5. Select your new Resource Group from he dropdown.
6. Select "North Europe" from the Location dropdown.
7. Click "OK" button

**Cluster Configuration**

1. Select Node type count of 1 (Unless you are configuring a different type of cluster)
2. Click the "Node type" section
3. Input the "Node type name" e.g. primary
4. Select relevant "Durability Tier" statless web api is OK at Bronze
5. Select required "Virtual Machine Size"
6. Select "Single node cluster" unless production dictates 5 nodes or more.
7. Alter the "Custom endpoints" to 80,8081
8. Check the "Enable reverse proxy"
9. Click "OK" button
10. Click "OK" button again

**Security**

1. Select Basic "Configuration Type"
2. Select the "CodeClinic" key vault
3. Input the name of your certificate
4. Click the "OK" button

**Summary**

1. Assuming validation passes, click the "this link" link contained within the information box.
2. A new browser tab will be opened and towards the bottom there is a "Download as a certificate" button, click this.
3. Close the new tab and then click the "Create" button

*IT WILL NOW TAKE SOME TIME TO CREATE AND DEPLOY YOUR CLUSTER, EASILY 20-30 MINUTES!*

Check to ensure that your Key Vault has the relevant "Advanced access properties" set by clicking the "Access Policies" menu option in the Key Vault blade and then click the link labelled "Click to show advanced access policies".

Ensure that the following options are checked: -

1. Enabled access to Azure Virtual machines for deployment
2. Enable access to Azure Resource Manager for template deployment

Install the certificate onto any development machine that will

1. Locate the pfx file downloaded to your machine
2. Double click the file from Windows Explorer
3. Select "Current User" click "Next" button
4. Click the "Next" button
5. Click the "Next" button, no password is allocated
6. Click "Place all certificates in the following store"
7. Click "Browse" and select the "Personal" store
8. Click the "Next" button
9. Click the "Finish" button

### Testing Connection

Go back to the Azure portal and click on your newly created clusters Overview and wait for the Updating message to disappear and the nodes to become available before proceeding any further!

Go to your Azure Key Vault and locate your certificate thumbprint and copy and paste it into notepad for use shortly.

**Service Fabric Explorer**

From within the Azure Portal locate the Service Fabric service and from the overview page click the "Service Fabric Explorer" link.

1. In Chrome you will receive the messages "Your connection is not private" / "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"
2. Click the "Proceed.." link at the bottom of the page
3. You will be presented with a popup asking you to select the certificate you wish to use

**NOTE**: I had some odd behaviour here, I would highly recommend closing down your browser at this point along with clearing your cache.

**Powershell ISE Command to Connect**

CONNECTION_ENDPOINT can be retrieved from the Azure Portal on the Cluster Overview blade
THUMBPRINT should have been copy and pasted earlier in the process, failing that it can be obtained from the Key Vault.

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint <CONNECTION_ENDPOINT> `
  -KeepAliveIntervalInSec 10 `
  -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint <THUMBPRINT> `
  -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue <THUMBPRINT> `
  -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My
```

Copy and paste the above into the Script window within the Powershell ISE command window which is accessible via a toolbar button, the character at the end of each line determines a carriage return.

Comment: Maybe post this answer *after* you've tried it? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I can understand that you are unable to connect to the cluster from your application or even from the cluster url right?
Then the reason behind are the following
1. ***Configure the exact port number from service manifest to the load balancer for health probe and backend pools(health probe is consumed by the backend pool).*** though during the creation of cluster you would have already connect to keyvault for Certificate, so power shell command is required for here .. if you have check the security tab in cluster window then you can find the certificate details which was configured during the cluster creation.

**2. once after this try to access using the following
https://custer url:service manifest or loadbalancer configured port number/controllerRoute/endpoint**